# How to launch Firefox with default profile using selenium 3.13.1 and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and after exhaustive research I can't find a reliable example to launch Firefox with my default profile so I retain my extensions, bookmarks etc. Much has changed and the examples I find are now deprecated or use Java syntax. Here's my set up:

- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- C# - Selenium WebDriver 3.13.1
- Selenium  WebDriver Support
- geckodriver - Firefox v. 61.0.1

References have been set on the solution. Here is my code:

```
FirefoxProfileManager myProfile = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = myProfile.GetProfile("C:\\Users\\Robert\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\4halwx5j.default");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;          

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

driver.Url = "https://lastpass.com/?ac=1&lpnorefresh=1";
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Would anyone be so kind to provide an example that works using WebDriver 3.13.1 FF v. 61.0.1and C# syntax?